# На какой программе программируют под Flash?

Tags: ide, flash

На какой программе программируют под Flash?

Comment: "программа, на которой программируют" называется IDE(Integrated Developer Environment, по русски - Интегрированная среда разработки. Это вам на будущее, что бы гуглилось лучше...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- [Adobe Flash Pro (Flash IDE)](http://www.adobe.com/go/tryflash/)
- [Adobe Flash Builder](http://www.adobe.com/products/flash-builder.html?promoid=FDUMA)
- [FlashDevelop](http://www.flashdevelop.org/)
- [IntelliJ IDEA](http://habrahabr.ru/post/111315/)

Answer (score 1):

Программируют под Flash платформу на языке программирования action script 3.0, основанном на ECMAScript.
Wiki Adobe Flash: [Adobe Flash. Материал из Википедии — свободной энциклопедии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adobe_Flash)

Для написания текстов на action script 3.0 вы можете использовать даже текстовый редактор. Многие текстовые редакторы поддерживают подсветку синтаксиса языка action script.
Стандартным расширением для скомпилированных flash-файлов (анимации, игр и интерактивных приложений) является SWF

Для компиляции понадобятся:  jdk, flex sdk
Для воспроизведения: Adobe Flash Player, Gnash или swfdec.
Популярные IDE в предыдущем ответе @ShockWave

PS. FlashDevelop - удобная IDE для программирования под Flash/ Flex платформы. 
Это личное мнение основанное на практике.